# How can I align my form the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me crazy and I hope someone can help me.
I am trying to align the form to the left so it is vertically in line with the text above (Compare your data). Any any ideas? Many thanks.

http://www.bootply.com/voJDzgVWDx

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: its because your `label for = "utility_type"` is occupying some space.
add `display:none` to its css.

Comment: there is a 15px padding on `.col-md-2` that you could fix  as well as a width in this media query:  `@media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-2 { {width: 16.66666667%;} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are nothing in your labels, so add `sr-only`  class to them.

Also, you can define a `no-margin` class, what actually has a `-15px` margin, and you can add it to first `col-md-2` div in the `form-group`.

http://www.bootply.com/vG7cIOvQFH

Comment: I never knew about sr-only. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `hidden-xs` too.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<label>` has `col-md-4` and so is occupying 4 columns although you don't have a label. When you have a label, it will be in line with `Compare your data`.

You can take a look at my [fork](http://www.bootply.com/KEp3UHK3a9)

I have also added a `padding-left:0px;` to the label.

Answer (score 1):

add your label after the dropdown:

[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/synG7KVtdo)

and similarly in other form fields too.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
 <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="utility_type"></label>
```

with this

```
 <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="utility_type"></label>
```

and you can also remove the padding from the `col-md-12` or put in inside a `row`

Answer (score 0):

See the below. Remove 'col-md-2'. And the first field will align to the left with the text above. Then do the same with the rest.

```
<!-- Select Basic -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="utility_type"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Its already aligned ... although you don't have any text in the label tags

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="utility_type">This is a label</label>
```

either you fill the label or remove it :)